# How to find the video associated with a previously read comment notification on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, notifications, comments

I had a notification on my mobile that there was a reply to my comment on some video I had watched. I clicked it open, but since my internet stopped working, I  quit the app.

When I thought of reading it later, I couldn't find the notification in the app anymore. I don't even know which video the comment was on, since the video did not load when I clicked on notification.

How do I find previously read notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to access the previous comments you have made on your account, go ahead and sign-in to the account, and from there you should be able to access the following: https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history

This will allow you to see each other the comments you have added to videos, in chronological order. Of course, if you would like to see if someone has posted a reply to that video (or in your case, had previously been forced to exit a notification window for whatever reason) there will be two links for each entry:

- The link that says "comment", will take you to your specific comment on that specific video, all replies included.
- The link that says the "Title of Video" will take you simply to the page the video was located on, leaving you free to sort the comments in whichever order you choose and scroll through them in that manner.